# Checking bash function arguments

Tags: bash, arguments

I would like to check if two arguments to a bash function are numeric, and the last argument is a directory that exists.

Have done like this, but the implementation is quite insufficient.

```
if   [[ $1 =~ "^[0-9]+$" ]]  \
  && [[ $2 =~ "^[0-9]+$" ]]  \
  && [[ -d $3 ]]
then
  do_something
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex metacharacters should not be quoted – `"^[0-9]+$"` tries to match `^[0-9]+$` as a string.

`man bash` says

> An  additional binary operator, =~, is available ...
>
> ... Any part of the pattern may be quoted to force the quoted portion to be matched as a string.